# Getting error in sqlmock for GoLang

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I am writing test cases for a GoLang application and i am using sqlmock for mocking the SQL queries but i am getting following error while executing **go test**

Params: [ call to query , was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedBegin => expecting database transaction Begin]

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means some SQL query was called which was not mocked.

Answer (score 1):

sqlmock expected a begin, but instead got something else. Show the function and test here for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, because I used `NamedExec` (not `NamedQuery`) to perform my update, but was mocking `ExpectQuery` in test

So,
if you have expression (i.e. use `UPDATE` or `INSERT`), you should use `ExpectExec`
if you have query (i.e. use `SELECT`), you should use `ExpectQuery`

It's obvious, but I stuck with it for couple of hours